# A little help with these sentences

Tags: translation

I was reading a manga and I was wondering if I understood, at least the first sentence well. The other two...hmmm, I don't know if I translated them so well, so I would need some assistance.
If it helps, the context is about money and friendship.

> 「この世の悩みのほとんどすべてはお金で解決できる」

This is the first sentence and I translated it as: The problems of this world (or rather society), most of them can be solved with money." (Have I gotten the gist of it?)

> 「お金で築ける友情がある」
>   「お金がないから築けない友情がある」

It's with these two sentences that I have problem to translate. 築く, looking in the dictionary, it means "to build, to construct, to amass", and I think the sentences are saying something about making friends with money?

Please, can someone clarify them for me? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of the first sentence is correct.

> お金で築ける友情がある。お金がないから築けない友情がある。
>   There is a friendship you can build with money. There is a friendship you cannot build because you don't have money.

Both sentences say 友情がある ("There is a friendship (of such and such a kind)"). お金で築ける and お金がないから築けない are relative clauses that modify 友情. 友情を築く is a set phrase, "to build/establish a friendship."